# What does the asterisk in the ULS log mean?

Tags: logging, uls

What does the asterisk at the end of the timestamp in the ULS log mean? Does this mean that this event has occurred multiple times?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is normally the line continuation character and is used whenever a particular message is too long to be included on a single line.  I can't say I've ever seen it used quite like is in the picture though.

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979595%28v=office.12%29.aspx), it means :

> A trace log message can have multiple "middle" sections. Trace log
>   messages are not guaranteed to appear consecutively within the trace
>   log. However, the "middle" and "end" messages contain an asterisk
>   beside the timestamp in the trace log. Developers can use the presence
>   of this asterisk to identify whether a line is a continuation of a
>   previous message. In addition, each line of the trace log includes the
>   ProcessID and ThreadID, enabling a developer to follow the flow of a
>   specific thread to see the surrounding messages.